# Openlayers 2 + HERE tiles caching

Tags: javascript, cors, maps, cross-domain, openlayers

I need to create an offline maps demo on a windows machine and the only option to do that is by using tile caching, I am using Openlayers 2, when I initialize an OSM layer everything works as expected:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap (CORS)", null, {
            eventListeners: {
                tileloaded: updateStatus,
                loadend: detect
        }})
    ]
}
```

The "detect" method is called and checking if the function getCanvasContext() can be called for a tile and everything works great!
When I replace the OSM with HERE maps using XYZ layer, it stops working:

```
var urlTpl = 'https://1.{base}.maps.cit.api.here.com' + '/{type}/2.1/maptile/newest/{scheme}/${z}/${x}/${y}/256/png' + '?app_id=?????&app_code=??????';

var hereLayer = {
  base: 'base',
  type: 'maptile',
  scheme: 'normal.day',
  app_id: platform['app_id'],
  app_code: platform['app_code']
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("HERE", [createUrl(urlTpl, hereLayer)], {
        eventListeners: {
                tileloaded: updateStatus,
                loadend: detect
            }
        })
    ]
}
```

In this example the detect method does being called but this time the function getCanvasContext() throws an exception:

> code: 18
>   message: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
>   name: SecurityError

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

From an answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71715/enabling-cors-in-openlayers: you will need to include a `tileOptions` setting in the `layers` options to enable CORS:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    layers: [
    new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("HERE", [createUrl(urlTpl, hereLayer)], {
    tileOptions: {crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous'},
    eventListeners: {
        tileloaded: updateStatus,
        loadend: detect
        }
    })
    ]
}
```